# Using an array for later use

Tags: php, arrays

I need to make an array in PHP from a table "artwork" that stores how many images there are and assigns a number to each image in a numeric sequence. I understand the concept but the how to is beyond me at this point.

Does anyone want to offer some help?

Comment: I guess you would use a database for this.

Comment: Is `artwork` a database table? Do you need to use the array later on the same script, or later on a different page? Or later on a different date in the future?

Comment: Yes, I have several tables, one is named artwork. I need to count certain records from different queries and use those numbers in different template.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT image_url FROM artwork";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $image_urls[] = $row[0];
}

foreach($image_urls as $key => $value) {
    echo "key: $key url: $value<br />";
}

?>
```

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: why in the world wouldnt you use $image_array[] instead of making a variable and incrementing it?

Comment: "that stores how many images there are and assigns a number to each image in a numeric sequence" the question is not clear, but understood that.

Comment: if you use $image_array[] you are paying an overhead for each operation to determine the next key and then the overhead of the array count.

Comment: please post proof of that statement.

Comment: Tomas, I think your idea is better. I am trying to do something like COUNT(*) AS RecordCount where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder. The problem I am having at the moment is conflicts with another query that needs to be run on the same table.

Comment: i don't have time to search the php internals. sorry.

Comment: i don't understand the "conflict" part.

Comment: I need to run: $result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder from artwork where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error()); So adding COUNT(*) AS RecordCount where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder to the same query is my conflict.

Comment: so, do the first query then $count = mysql_num_rows($result), i don't see the big picture.

Comment: I think you're overwriting always the same position here:  $image_array[$i] = $row[0];
$count++;
Note that $i does not increment.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't take it personally, but you have a talent of asking extremely ambiguous questions, with title contradicts with the body and with comments contradicts with them both.

What does mean "that stores how many images there are"? You need a number? Why array then? 
You need images? Why distinct "how many" then?  Having an array implies that you ALWAYS can have a count of it's members.

Which images? Images returned by the query or ALL images stored in the database?

What's the point in having count(*) in the query?

Why can't you simply tell us, which kind of PHP page you are trying to write and thus get easy and complete answer implementing simple general purpose techniques and so have not a single problem to fight with?